# How to convert numeric string with space as thousands separator to float?

Tags: python, locale

I'm trying to convert a string that has a space as thousand separator, which is used in Swedish locale, but I'm unable to do it with below method, but I don't understand why it doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm constrained to try to solve this using locale.

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'sv_SE')
print(locale.atof('33 000,00'))

>>> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '33 000.00'
```

```py
print(locale.localeconv())
>>> {'int_curr_symbol': '', 'currency_symbol': '', 'mon_decimal_point': '', 
'mon_thousands_sep': '', 'mon_grouping': [], 'positive_sign': '', 
'negative_sign': '', 'int_frac_digits': 127, 'frac_digits': 127, 
'p_cs_precedes': 127, 'p_sep_by_space': 127, 'n_cs_precedes': 127, 
'n_sep_by_space': 127, 'p_sign_posn': 127, 'n_sign_posn': 127, 
'decimal_point': ',', 'thousands_sep': '\xa0', 'grouping': [3, 0]}
```

Comment: What does `print(locale.localeconv()['thousands_sep'])` print? Maybe the locale does not have configured a blank there but a dot? I got the same error like you with German locale but with '.' instead of ' ' it worked.

Comment: I recommend you to strip all space characters. One problem is that locales may use a tiny space, but so the `atof` may not be able to work in the inverse direction. BTW, which OS are you using?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for the input! I'm using Windows

Answer (score 0):

Well a naive method would be:

```
s = '33 000,00'

s = float(s.replace(' ', '').replace(',','.'))

print(s)
```

Output:

```
33000.0
```

Comment: Thank you @Synthase, you are right! But I'm constrained to using locale and if not possible I will have to revert back yo using the naive method